# Software to update Android phone

Tags: android

I was wondering is there any free software that can update the Android on a smartphone?

This question might seem a little off topic, as most latest smartphones running on Android are factory preset to update its Android whenever a new version is released, but unfortunately there are still some that are not.

So I've got one of those that are not. However I love my phone and really don't want to change it as for now. So any advises?

Comment: What? Just don't install the OTA update?

Comment: There is such software, but it's pretty much device depending. No "general updater" software I've heard of (and I'm quite active on the Android side). It also often depends on whether you want to use "stock software" (provided by the manufacturer) or 3rd party (aka "Custom ROMs"). So a generic answer is hard to give.

Comment: You could investigate http://www.cyanogenmod.org/ to see if it is compatible with your device.  Otherwise go to the manufacturers website and look for updates.  Motorola has them for certain models.

Comment: I thought you're looking for software to *apply/manage* updates – but reading your question again, you could also be asking for the ROM-update itself. I'd suggest you take a look at the [update tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/update/info) at our sister site, which gives you some starters – and maybe [edit] your question to make clear which part you mean: software on your computr to *manage/perform* device updates, or the updated Android-ROMs themselves.

Comment: I also support using CyanogenMod. It is awesome.

Comment: The problem with Android is that it's not "Android" that runs on your phone but a customized mod of it specifically designed to run on your phone's hardware. If nobody maintains that specific mod, that can run on your device and updates it to the latest Android release, you won't get any update. It's impossible to build a software that can update Android on any device as soon as a new version of Android is released.

Comment: @Izzy - yes I was looking for ROM updates, but now I realize it's not as simple and safe as I thought it would be. And as my phone is like few months old and still in it warranty period I don't think I should go for it, at least not at this stage.

Comment: I get your point and fully understand. I remember how afraid I was the first time :) Luckily, in most cases it turns out to be rather easy. And as long as you're careful (read all the instructions and follow them, pick the correct images, etc), "real danger" is quite absent. Not that I'm a "daily flasher" now :) The most tricky part is getting started and absolve the first steps. But you're correct: Better first learn about it more thoroughly, so you really know what you're doing then. Better safe than sorry :)

Answer (score 2):

Which is your mobile ?? it's model ? Vendor ?? you get OTA updates in your country region only if your vendor developed New version for your handset.

for Ex. In the case of Samsung devices they provide OTA updates for newer android verions(KK,Lollipop) mainly for flagship models(S4,S5,Note 3,Note 4 ect) and sometimes for other models(Note 3 Neo,Note 2 etc) also.

In my case now am using `Samsung Galaxy Note 3 Neo`, when I bought this device it android Version was `4.3(Jelly Bean)` and my phone's country region was `UAE`.After month `Samsung` released `4.4.2 (KitKat)` update for my phone model only for INDIAN Region Phones. i.e. the device in other region wont get this update via OTA.

But in this case we can update new firmware (OS) manually without affecting `Warranty` with the help samsung firmware flashing application called `ODIN`, To do this we need to download latest `firmware` from [SAMMOBILES](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/)

just see the below image of `firmwares` for different `country/region` of **`Samsung Galaxy Note 3 Neo SM-N750`** Model

[image]

See [How to flash Samsung Stock Rom using Odin](http://androidxda.com/flash-samsung-stock-rom-using-odin).

If device vendor not released any OTA or Firmwares then you need to go for `Custom Roms`

[**CyanogenMod**](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/).

is an aftermarket firmware for a number of cell phones based on the open-source Android operating system. It offers features not found in the official Android based firmwares of vendors.

see your device is listed [here](http://download.cyanogenmod.org/) or [here](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Devices#vendor=;).

[List of devices supported by CyanogenMod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_devices_supported_by_CyanogenMod)

still you cant find a *ROM or Firmware or Latest android version* for your device you must look into [**xda-developers.com**](http://forum.xda-developers.com/),

The site's main purpose is discussion, troubleshooting and development for Android, Windows Phone, WebOS, Ubuntu Touch, Firefox OS and Tizen phones. The site also offers Windows Mobile and Android users general information about devices, ROM upgrades, technical support, Q&A, and reviews of device applications and accessories. Separate forums exist for each model of phones manufactured by Sony, HTC, Samsung, LG, Motorola, and many others. Forums are also available for tablets and many other devices.

Read more about `xda-developers` from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XDA_Developers)

If you have time, patience then try to know [CREATE OWN ROM FOR ANY ANDROID DEVICE](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1801690)

---

Comment: So most probably I won't be able to update it. I have a Chinese phone. Not sure what the name of the vendor actually is. I know they also produce HammerPhones (if you've heard about them). The model is 706_v92_jbla_fhd, they've called it S5 G9000 and it's something like a replica of Samsung S5.

Comment: @RamzyShah [Not Sure] just go through http://www.needrom.com/download/tengda-s5-g9000-4-4-2-kitkat/ and http://www.needrom.com/download/tengda-s5-dapeng-g9000/

Comment: The links you've provided are really useful. However as I already said to Izzy, my phone is still new and in its warranty period so I guess I'll get back to this idea to update its Android at later stage, when if I mess something up I won't be sorry :-)